# Data scraping from coinmarketcap

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Hello i'm trying to **scrape** the market table at the end of this page "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/markets/"

This is what I tried

```
crpyto_url <- read_html("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/markets/")
Exchanges <- crpyto_url %>% 
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

This is the error

```
Error in if (is.character(txt) && length(txt) == 1 && nchar(txt, type = "bytes") < : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I don't think that the error is relevant, I think that the real problem is that I don't know how to find the xpath related with the table.

If someone manage to find the xpath, can you please explain what was the process to found it. Or link some resources.

Thanks

I.

Comment: Instead of trying to access the data via web scraping, have you thought about using their API? There's an R package for pulling data from this website. Read about it here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coinmarketcapr/coinmarketcapr.pdf

Comment: That table is loaded via JS, so `rvest` would need some kind of API/XHR. Alternatively you can look into `RSelenium` for JS scraping.

Comment: Yes, I tried the API but it seems really limited if you use the free version. I'm going to keep looking though. I'm going to check RSelenium thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the coingecko API.

```
url <- "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/tickers"
Exchanges <- GET(url)
araw_data <- fromJSON(content(Exchanges, as = "text",encoding = "UTF-8"))
araw_data$tickers$market %>% select(name) %>% pull
```